# I want to show latest 3 post from non wordpress website to my wordpress cms using rss feed

Tags: php, rss, wordpress, feed

I want to display a list of post from a non wordpress website to my wordpress website using RSS. I want to show a thumbnail, short desc, link, title and style them.

I tried with "feedwordpress" plugins, but still cant find the exact solution. Please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in your template via the fetch_feed function (powered by SimplePie):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

Comment: Thank you Ralph, it really helped. I want to display it in http://anjan.com.np/itmedia "ACTUALITÉ & DOSSIERS IT" format, original content "www.itpro.fr" Actualités et Dossiers Informatiques Section.

Any help??

Comment: It looks like you figured it out, but you could pull from: http://www.itpro.fr/feed/